# HTML/JS - detecting Android software VERSION (and switching css file)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm making an app with Phonegap build. Android 2.3 and below do not support css float, and android 3.0 and above do.

I need a different CSS file for each.

Is there a way to detect the Android SOFTWARE VERSION and change the css file depending on this?

Can I either do this with JavaScript or HTML?

I know you can detect IE with `<!--[if IE]>`, but is it possible to detect android versions?

Answer (score 2):

Your technique is ok, but it's static and can lead to more problems in the future when referring to OS-types and system-types. It's better to check if the tag is supported in general. The best way to do this is with JavaScript, like this:

```
if('float' in document.body.style) {
    // jQuery?
    $('#myAwesomeDiv').css('float', 'left')
}
```

You can also make a short function for it to TRUE/FALSE it:

```
function propertyExist(property) {
    if(property in document.body.style) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (propertyExists('float')) {
        // Do nothing?
}
    else {
        // Change the style (use jQuery, jquery.com)
        $("link").attr("href","non_float.css");
        $("head").append("<link>");
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to send me an example code with it working? If float is supported, I would like it to do          document.write("<link href='main4.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>"); and if not it would be          document.write("<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>"); ... I have been tinkering with it for over an hour and can't get it:(

Comment: Or if it's not possible to write to the document like that, how could I just switch the CSS files so main.css is when Float is NOT supported, and main4.css is when Float IS supported.